# tracking mouse events not related to controls in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I need to write event handlers for tracking mouse movements, but the mouse-down and mouse-up events are not related to any Control object. What is the generic way to do this? On researching this question on StackOverflow, I found a lot of information about mouse events related to specific controls, such as the PictureBox, but I don't find any on C# generic mouse listeners. I did find a much older question, but it wasn't related to C#.

Comment: I noticed this in msdn article: Invoking an event can only be done from within the class that declared the event. So how would I listen for mouse movements not related to a specific form. (This is a winforms application.) Here is the link to the MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I think I might have found a related answer in this StackOver flow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316693/screen-capture-target-area-of-the-desktop

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "not related"?

Comment: Hi, DrKoch. I mean that I don't want my mouse movements to be specific to the Windows Form, but to the screen. I was trying to capture a region of the screen.

Comment: You need a hook to track the mouse if it is not interacting with your UI.  Not directly covered by the framework, the pinvoke for SetWindowsHookEx is widely available.  You don't actually need a hook to do this, find sample code in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3124252/17034).