# How to capture a screenshot for a specific component in an application's window using c#?

Tags: c#, screenshot, capture

Please I need to take a screenshot for a specific application - design tool - but just for the design area or component not the whole application's window , is there a way in C# that I could use to get the handle of the design component and take a screenshot.

Comment: did you tried to check over google?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316693/screen-capture-target-area-of-the-desktop

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link but what I am looking for is a little bit different , I want a code that uses the application's windows handle to get a list of it's components and then capture a screenshot for it and Yes I checked on google but didn't find what I want. What I can do now is capturing the whole window using copyfromscreen function

Comment: What do you mean by design component? A specific control?

Comment: It's a canvas where there is a specific design drawn